# To Center Text To UITextView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextview

I want to text center to `uitextview`

don't

```
textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

Explanation in the picture

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`NSTextAlignmentCenter` is actually the way to go. Just make sure the view is wide enough to fit the text, or stretch it to fill the screen width.

If you're programmatically creating the `UITextView`, you'll need to set the frame like.-

```
textView.frame = CGRectMake(0, (SCREEN_HEIGHT - TEXT_VIEW_HEIGHT) / 2, SCREEN_WIDTH, TEXT_VIEW_HEIGHT);
```

Comment: I want to write in center Length and width http://i.stack.imgur.com/itgLy.png ، Thank you

Comment: Do you mean "vertical alignment"? Try to search for it...